# Why my code is Time Limit Exceeded (leetcode104)

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am solving some exercises at [leetcode 104](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/description/)

**Desciption :**  *Given a binary tree, find its maximum depth.
The maximum depth is the number of nodes along the longest path from the root node down to the farthest leaf node.*

Here  is  my  solution

```
  public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
      if(root ==null ) {
         return 0 ;
      }   
      return ( maxDepth(root.left)+1) > (maxDepth(root.right)+1 ) ?
             (maxDepth(root.left)+1):(maxDepth(root.right)+1);
  }
```

But it throws  `Time Limit Exceeded` .

Then  I  change it  to  this  ,it runs well and  accepted

```
 public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
          if(root ==null ) {
             return 0 ;
          }
          int left  = maxDepth(root.left)+1;
          int right = maxDepth(root.right) +1 ;
          return left > right ? left :right ; 
        }
```

But  I don't think  they have any differences . Please  help  me  to understad where I had made the mistake . 
Thanks for  your guide, cheers!

Comment: Add a println statement to your `maxDepth` method and you will see the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: thanks a lot  for  your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably four method call

```
(maxDepth(root.left)+1) > (maxDepth(root.right)+1 ) ?
(maxDepth(root.left)+1):(maxDepth(root.right)+1)
```

Here you are calling the maxDepth method 4 times which is not efficient.

Calculations for root.left and root.right are duplicated recursion calls which are not necessary. Try to think and optimize your solution by reducing the number of method calls and this will make your code execute within much faster.

Your second code snippet involves only 2 recursive method calls, making it a better performing solution.

You can even use a much simpler solution:

```
if (root == null) {
    return 0;
}
return Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right)) + 1;
```

Comment: it is useful   ,could you tell me  which is . faster  'Math.max()'     method  or      'Ternary Operator'

Comment: just  in compare